# Will my audience understand the phrase "lead time"?

Tags: expressions, terminology

> ...results in a relatively long lead time for our software products.

Should I use this expression in an article for average software developers? (i.e. an international Java magazine) Would it generally be understood?

Comment: I think it's a business phrase more than a software-developer phrase. I'd expect the answer to whether a person is familiar with "lead time" is about the same as whether the person is familiar with, say, "deliverable". In any case, whenever there is doubt about whether a phrase will be understood, it's always safe to rephrase.

Answer (score 14):

I would say that most educated people, especially those used to working in project environments, will understand the term.

Comment: This. It would be understood by almost anybody in the U.S., at least, and I'm sure by 99.9999% of those who had occasion to read a Java magazine.

Comment: Also: software developers are usually good at groking the meaning of a word from context: if the rest of the sentence gives a few hints at what it could mean, then you should be golden.

Comment: He did say it is an "international" magazine, so many readers are not native speakers of English.

Comment: Be careful though of lead(time)/lead(metal). Supposedly Led Zeppelin made that their spelling so people would call them 'leed' Zep!

Comment: You don't mention where you are from, but as @Robusto can confirm that this is in common usage in American English, I can confirm that it is in common usage in British English too, at least in Engineering and Software Engineering circles.

Comment: @Robusto初夢 I'm a Danish Computer Science student and have often used Java and read Java-related English articles, but I've never heard of "lead time" before. I think your assumption is a bit naive.

Comment: @Kristian - it's more a business than specifically programming term. Even then it's more common in manufacturing where you often have a long wait for parts to be made

Answer (score 6):

I have been in development for about 6 years now, and I came over here to find out what **lead time** means.

I asked around and four other people don't know what this means. I think it is not commonly used.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_time):

> A lead time is the latency (delay) between the initiation and
>   execution of a process.

Does it mean the same in Java?

Comment: Where are you located? Maybe that's a factor

Comment: Is that Java the island, or Java the programming language?